# Confusion with loops in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

i have to make a program with the following condition: A delivery guy deliver stacks(packs) of beer to different shops

- 1st shop, 1 stack
- 2nd shop, 2 stacks
- 3rd shop, 3 stacks
- ...
- until 10th shop.

The program must print it like this :

```
int i1,shop[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},stacks[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},counter;
for (i1 = 9; i1 >= 0; i1--){
for(counter=0;counter<=i1;counter++){

printf("Shop[%i] %i \t",shop[i1], stacks[i1]);
}
```

It's running but the output is not what I want :

> Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10
>   Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10
>   Shop[10] 10     Shop[10] 10     Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] 9
>   Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] 9
>   Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] 9       Shop[9] etc.

It must look like this:

> - Shop 1 - 1
> - Shop 2 - 2, 2
> - Shop 3 - 3, 3, 3
> - Shop 4 - 4, 4, 4, 4.

Comment: Then why did you format your print to give the wrong output? Also what is the point of the inner `for` loop? - Have you read the documentation for [escape sequences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape)?

Comment: If you want to count upwards, then why did you write your outer loop to count downwards?

Comment: Thank for the swift answer :) I thought the problem is in the loops but i format it i i moved the printf("Shop [i1]") in the outer for and it worked .

Comment: No i haven`t i`m pretty new in programming and i`ll definitely read it .

Comment: Use two loops, the external to write Shop %i -, the internal to write the content, after it print \n in order to break to a new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your loops scrambled. Here is a piece of code that will print what you want. Modify the code so it access the right arrays and print their contents:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    printf("Shop %d - ", i);

    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        printf("%d, ", i);

    putchar('\n');
}
```

The first loop (with `i`), will print the "Shop  - " string, 10 times. The second loop will run *for every iteration of the first loop*, thus, giving you the correct numbers of prints. Minor code changes will take core of the comma printing...

Outputs:

```
Shop 1 - 1, 
Shop 2 - 2, 2, 
Shop 3 - 3, 3, 3, 
Shop 4 - 4, 4, 4, 4, 
Shop 5 - 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
Shop 6 - 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
Shop 7 - 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
Shop 8 - 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
Shop 9 - 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
Shop 10 - 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
```

Comment: Yes i`ve made the same  just didnt use the putchar statement .Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use multiple `printf` statements to produce each line of output.  Put

```
printf( "Shop %d", i1 );
```

in your *outer* loop (no newline).

Within your *inner* loop, you'll *just* print out the value of `stacks[i1]` (again, with no newlines):

```
printf( " %d", stacks[i1] );
```

You'll have to write a newline in a separate statement *after* the inner loop has finished:

```
putchar( '\n' );
```

Don't worry about commas or other separators for now.

Make those changes, and that'll get you most of the way there.

**Edit**

Your inner loop should check against `stacks[i1]`, rather than `i1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output to appear on separate lines you need to put in a `\n` new line character at the end of the string like this rather than the tab character you've got currently.

```
printf("Shop[%i] %i \n",shop[i1], stacks[i1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, please get used to write clean code so its more readeable, and your question more organized. Is this what you want?

```
int i1;
int shop[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int stacks[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int counter;

//To go through the shops
for (i1 = 0; i1 < 10; i1++){

    printf("Shop[%i] - ",i1); 
    //to go through the packs
    for(counter=0;counter<=i1;counter++){
        printf("%i", stacks[counter]);
    }

    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Yes exactly and i`ll try to make more readable code from now on

Comment: remember to mark it as the answer if its the one you are using ;)

Answer (score 0):

To output the pattern there is no need to use arrays. You can output it using loops.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    const char *Title = "Shop %u - %u";

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        unsigned int item = i + 1;

        printf( Title, item, item );

        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            printf( ", %u", item );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Shop 1 - 1
Shop 2 - 2, 2
Shop 3 - 3, 3, 3
Shop 4 - 4, 4, 4, 4
Shop 5 - 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
Shop 6 - 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
Shop 7 - 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
Shop 8 - 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
Shop 9 - 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9
Shop 10 - 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

Pay attention to that there is no redundant last comma in the output.

If to define the variable `Title` the following way

```
const char *Title = "Shop %2u - %u";
                          ^^^
```

then the output will be more aligned.

```
Shop  1 - 1
Shop  2 - 2, 2
Shop  3 - 3, 3, 3
Shop  4 - 4, 4, 4, 4
Shop  5 - 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
Shop  6 - 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
Shop  7 - 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
Shop  8 - 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
Shop  9 - 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9
Shop 10 - 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```

Also you could define the variable like

```
const char *Title = "Shop %2u - %2u";
                          ^^^   ^^^
```

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const unsigned int N = 10;
    const char *Title = "Shop %2u - %2u";

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        unsigned int item = i + 1;

        printf( Title, item, item );

        for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            printf( ", %2u", item );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Shop  1 -  1
Shop  2 -  2,  2
Shop  3 -  3,  3,  3
Shop  4 -  4,  4,  4,  4
Shop  5 -  5,  5,  5,  5,  5
Shop  6 -  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6
Shop  7 -  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7
Shop  8 -  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8,  8
Shop  9 -  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9,  9
Shop 10 - 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
```